# Printing to fiscal thermal printer issue

Tags: c#, thermal-printer, fiscal

I have an project and it support all printer but not the thermal printer(fiscal),In my app i have the option example when u print the receipt u have to choose the printer and the fiscal printer doesnt show there,so ill need to change the code my printer is model : fp 700, my project is a c# project here is my print code

```
   private void btnPrintReceipt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parameter.autoprintid = "2";
        POSPrintRpt mkc = new POSPrintRpt(lblReceiptNo.Text);
        mkc.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: What driver did you install for the printer?  Was it a vendor driver or a standard Microsoft driver?  What interface is the printer (USB, Serial, IP)?  There may be a better driver.  Check printer manufacturer website and make sure you have the latest driver.

Comment: The thermal printer is fp 700  i think it is serial..? my pos system doesnt recognize the printer

Comment: I found the spec for the printer.  It supports serial, but it looks like Ethernet has more options.  I would talk to the POS support people.  It is possible that you just need to install the correct driver.  See : http://www.datecs.bg/en/downloads/pdf?id=FP-700.pdf

Comment: The drivers are installed but it still doesnt print, should i change the code or i just have to edit printer settings in windows ?

Comment: Can you print from another app (not c#)?

Comment: Yes u can print from another app but i actually use c# for my pos ... so i dont know how to solve this error

Comment: Are you using same printer name as when you are working?

Comment: Yes same printer name, it works with other pos but mine not ?..

Comment: Are you sure you are using the exact same name?  Some printers support both PDF and XPS (post script) and selecting the wrong printer can cause issue.  If it is ethernet you can directly connect to printer.  But you need to send the correct configuration bits to the printer before sending data.  For example to put printer into PDF or XPS mode.

Comment: yes the printer is using ethernet?

Comment: Are the working apps using ethernet?  Are you connecting by the name in Control Panel or the IP address directly?

Comment: Yes. my pos dont recognize the printer

Comment: The you need to send configuration messages to the printer before sending the print data.  The is what the drivers automatically do.  Since you do not have the driver you have to add to your code the equivalent to what the driver will do.  What you can do since it is ethernet is to take a PC with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the configuration data when writing from a app that works so you can see the difference from what your code is doing.